# Same values don't change but different ones need to be concat when using pandas?

Tags: pandas

Example:

```
    A      B     C      
0   id1    b1    91
1   id1    b1    350
2   id2    a2    90
3   id2    a4    90
4   id2    a5    90
5   id3    c1    180

The type
col A: string
col B: string
col C: string
```

Expected Output:

```
    A      B           C      
0   id1    b1        '91,350'
1   id2    a2,a4,a5    '90'
2   id3    c1          '180'
```

I want to groupby `column A` to get expected output, but I don't know how to set function to get it like `pd.groupby('A')`.

Notice: the type of expected output columns are all string. And values are merge by `','`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `str`, then using `groupby` with `unique`

```
s=df.astype(str).groupby('A',as_index=False).agg(lambda x : ','.join(x.unique()))
s
     A         B       C
0  id1        b1  91,350
1  id2  a2,a4,a5      90
2  id3        c1     180
```